# Can't change mysql data folder CentOS 6

Tags: mysql, centos, selinux

I've a server with CentOS 6.3 and Mysql installed on.
I've created two partition, one for system and the bigger one for data mounted in /data
Right after installed Mysql I've created the dir /data/mysql then as root I changed the selinux context of this folder typing `chcon -R -t mysqld_db_t /data/mysql` and modified the Mysql configuration file (my.cnf) to this:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/data/mysql
socket=/data/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
symbolic-link=0

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

but now i can't start mysqld service! It give me Can't change dir to /data/mysql (errcode 13)

This is the output of the `ls -Z /data | grep mysql`:

```
drwxr-xr-x. mysql mysql system_u:object_r:mysqld_db_t:s0 mysql
```

The strange thing is that every time I try to start the mysqld service and it fails the context of myslq dir become `system_u:object_r:default_t:s0` and two dirs (mysql and test) are created in it.

Anyway if I disable selinux evreything works great....

Answer (score 1):

You need to [use `semanage fcontext`](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security-Enhanced_Linux/sect-Security-Enhanced_Linux-SELinux_Contexts_Labeling_Files-Persistent_Changes_semanage_fcontext.html) to set the default file context for your non-standard location for the MySQL databases.

```
semanage fcontext -a -t mysqld_db_t "/data/mysql(/.*)?"
```

Once done, use `restorecon` to fix any mislabeled files/directories:

```
restorecon -r -v /data/mysql
```

Now you should have no further SELinux issues.

Answer (score -4):

I have the same problem, and I solved:

The problem is permission, my.cnf execute mysqld whit user mysql
[mysqld]
datadir=/data/mysql
socket=/data/mysql/mysql.sock
**user=mysql**
symbolic-link=0

Then I move used mysql files and references all over /var/lib/mysql/, 
then I modified:

/etc/my.cnf

> > [mysqld] 
> > datadir=/var/lib/mysql
> > socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
> > user=mysql
> > # Default to using old password format for compatibility with mysql 3.x
> > # clients (those using the mysqlclient10 compatibility package).
> > old_passwords=1
> >
> > # Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks;
> > # to do so, uncomment this line:
> > # symbolic-links=0
> > [mysqld_safe]
> > log-error=/var/lib/mysql/mysqld.log
> > pid-file=/var/lib/mysql/mysqld.pid

/etc/init.d/mysqld

> > get_mysql_option mysqld datadir "/var/lib/mysql"
> > datadir="$result"
> > get_mysql_option mysqld socket "$datadir/mysql.sock"
> > socketfile="$result"
> > get_mysql_option mysqld_safe log-error "/var/lib/mysql/mysqld.log"
> > errlogfile="$result"
> > get_mysql_option mysqld_safe pid-file "/var/lib/mysql/mysqld.pid"
> > mypidfile="$result"
> >
> > .
> > .
> > .
> >   fi
> >   [ $ret -eq 0 ] && touch /var/lib/mysql/mysqld.lock (this and another reference to lock file.)
> >   return $ret

I change the name of **mysql** lock file by **mysqld.lock** in /etc/init.d/mysqld
but is not necesary.

finally I change owner of /var/lib/mysql
chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql -R

and set permissions:

chmod 755 /var/lib/mysql -R

now

/etc/init.d/mysqld start

Comment: You do not seem to have the same problem as the person who posted this question.

Comment: You're absolutely right, it's just like, because the error that I was getting in mysqld.log
was the same.